# Left join in not working

Tags: mysql

I am working on opencart project. In admin Panel, I want to list only those products which does not belongs to category id 71 even the product is not map with any category.

Below is my query to fetch products according to condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nu_product p 
LEFT JOIN nu_product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN nu_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p2c.category_id != '71' 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY p.product_id DESC 
LIMIT 0,20
```

But the above condition gives me only products which does not belongs to category id 71. And products which are not belongs to any category are not showing. I want to show them as well.
So, please tell me what is wrong with the above query. Am i miss something in above query.

Comment: move your `WHERE` condition in the `ON` clause. `FROM  nu_product p
  LEFT JOIN nu_product_to_category p2c
   ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id
    AND p2c.category_id != '71'
  LEFT JOIN nu_product_description pd
   ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
    AND pd.language_id = '1'`

Comment: After applying your changes in query, it also showing products which belongs to category id 71.

Comment: Its not clear to what you expect the result to be. Perhaps the first join should be a inner join. Do all products have a category?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `NULL` `category_id`s. The expression `NULL != '71'` evaluates to `NULL`, (which is obviously not `true`), and thus the `p2c.category_id != '71'` condition excludes them. 
In order to resolves this issue, you must explicitly handles those `NULL`s, e.g., like this:

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      nu_product p 
LEFT JOIN nu_product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN nu_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
WHERE     pd.language_id = '1' AND (p2c.category_id IS NULL OR p2c.category_id != '71')
GROUP BY  p.product_id 
ORDER BY  p.product_id DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: @user2393886 if this solves your problem, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM nu_product p 
LEFT JOIN nu_product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id) and p2c.category_id != '71' 
LEFT JOIN nu_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) and pd.language_id = '1'
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY p.product_id DESC 
LIMIT 0,20
```

Try this basically your where clause was changing it to an inner join.